# Angular: Why is my div not showing/hiding with ng-show/ng-hide?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, ng-show

I'm trying to make a super simple lightbox for some images. Basically I have a div with a set of images showing up using ng-repeat, and I want to have a lightbox div show up when one of the images is clicked. I can't figure out why my lightbox div won't appear. Here is my code:

```js
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('PhotosCtrl', ['$scope', function PhotosCtrl($scope){
 $scope.photos = [
  {
   src: '/images/img1.png',
   caption: ' '
  },
  {
   src: '/images/img2.png',
   caption: ' '
  }
 ];
 $scope.larges = [
  {
   src: '/images/img1-lg.png',
   caption: ' '
  },
  {
   src: '/images/img2-lg.png',
   caption: ' '
  }
 ];
}]);
```

```css
.photowrap{
 max-width: 85%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 12px 0;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: #fff;
}
.photos{
 margin: 0;
}
.photo{
 max-height: 250px;
 border: 2px solid #EBEBEB;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
p.caption{
 display: none;
}

.lightbox{
 max-width: 85%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
 position: absolute;
}
.lbphoto{
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="PhotosCtrl" class="content">
  <div class="photowrap">
    <a href="" ng-repeat="photo in photos" ng-click="showme=true" class="photos">
      <img ng-src="{{photo.src}}" class="photo img-responsive"/>
    </a>
    <div ng-show="showme" class="lightbox">
      <a href="" ng-repeat="large in larges" class="photos">
        <a ng-click="showme=false" class="close">x</a>
        <img ng-src="{{large.src}}" class="lbphoto img-responsive"/>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because on each iteration `ng-repeat` does create a prototypically inherited child scope. So while creating child scope, `object` value gets passed with there reference inside child scope but the primitive type values are just passes there initial value. When primitive types value(here `showme`) gets modified inside the child scope, that variable creates a new copy inside child scope(when `ng-click` of inner `ng-repeat` chnages the value of `showme` it will be new variable copy of `showme`). You could solve such kind of issue by taking help of reference type `objects`.

Here what you can do is, make `showme` property as a part of outer `ng-repeat` which `photo` element. By which you will ensure that you are relying on the reference `object` which is `photo`.

Also you have to move `ng-repeat` to one step above, so that `photo` object will get avaialble inside `inner` `ng-repeat`, currently both the `ng-repeat` on same level.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="PhotosCtrl" class="content">
  <div class="photowrap" ng-repeat="photo in photos">
    <a href="" ng-click="photo.showme=true" class="photos">
      <img ng-src="{{photo.src}}" class="photo img-responsive"/>
    </a>
    <div ng-show="photo.showme" class="lightbox">
      <a href="" ng-repeat="large in larges" class="photos">
        <a ng-click="photo.showme=false" class="close">x</a>
        <img ng-src="{{large.src}}" class="lbphoto img-responsive"/>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I applied your suggestions but I still see nothing when I click on my images.

Comment: @fastasleep check updated answer, Thanks for heads up

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code:

1- `ng-repeat` creates a child scope, so you have to use `.` syntax for setting a variable and use it later on.

2- your `ng-repeat` is on `a` tag, since your `ng-show` in on the `div` below, it means the photo is not available there. You have to move your `ng-repeat` one level higher.

So:

```
<div ng-controller="PhotosCtrl" class="content">
  <div class="photowrap" ng-repeat="photo in photos">
    <a href="" ng-click="photo.showme=true" class="photos">
      <img ng-src="{{photo.src}}" class="photo img-responsive"/>
    </a>
    <div ng-show="photo.showme" class="lightbox">
      <a href="" ng-repeat="large in larges" class="photos">
        <a ng-click="photo.showme=false" class="close">x</a>
        <img ng-src="{{large.src}}" class="lbphoto img-responsive"/>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```